# node-oracledb error when executing a stored procedure

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I'm using Node 10.x,and Oracledb 3.0

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in node.js

I've Exception block in the procedure,like below:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
OUT_STATUS:='FAILURE';
OUT_STATUS_DESC:='USER NOT MAPPED TO A GROUP';
WHEN OTHERS THEN
OUT_STATUS:='FAILURE';
OUT_STATUS_DESC:=dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
```

whenever control goes to Exception block throwing below error in node.js.

> Error: ORA-24338: statement handle not executed

But,explicitly if i execute procedure in db with same IN parameters it's giving proper OUT parameters with error and CURSOR is closed.

These are the OUT parameter types in procedure.

`OUT_STATUS OUT VARCHAR2,
 OUT_STATUS_DESC OUT VARCHAR2,
 OUT_MENU_NAME OUT SYS_REFCURSOR`

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All OUT variables must be set to something even if you don't intend to use them in the node-oracledb code, see https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/886

It turns out this is true in all Oracle DB drivers (e.g. node-oracledb) based on Oracle's C 'OCI' API, but symptomatic problems are more commonly seen in node-oracledb.

Comment: @Christoper Jones, Thanks for your information.So there is no fix available for this issue am i right?

Comment: It is being tracked in Oracle bug 22813401 which is still open.

Comment: @kashiviswanath You asked, "So there is no fix available for this issue am i right?" Just wanted to point out that, although there's no fix yet, the thread that Chris linked to does have a workaround.

Comment: A fix has been made and will appear in the next major Oracle DB release (whatever comes after the current 21c release).

Answer (score 0):

A work-around is, if it has not been opened before then open the `OUT_MENU_NAME` cursor with zero rows in the exception blocks:

```sql
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    OUT_STATUS:='FAILURE';
    OUT_STATUS_DESC:='USER NOT MAPPED TO A GROUP';

    -- Replicate your normal cursor output and filter on something that will never be true:
    OPEN  OUT_MENU_NAME FOR
      SELECT 'Nothing'         AS col1,
             DATE '1970-01-01' AS col2,
             0                 AS col3
      FROM DUAL
      WHERE 1 = 0;

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    OUT_STATUS:='FAILURE';
    OUT_STATUS_DESC:=dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;

    -- Replicate your normal cursor output and filter on something that will never be true:
    OPEN  OUT_MENU_NAME FOR
      SELECT 'Nothing'         AS col1,
             DATE '1970-01-01' AS col2,
             0                 AS col3
      FROM DUAL
      WHERE 1 = 0;
```